# Regex URL not validating as expected in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am attempting to validate URLs with the following RegExp in Dart

```
r"(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?"
```

In test using RegexBuddy it passes in Perle and JavaScript regex agains the following URLS

```
http://www.regexbuddy.com
http://www.regexbuddy.com/
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library
You can download RegexBuddy at http://www.regexbuddy.com/download.html.
```

Its usage is as shown below:

In my polymer component

```
      <paper-input floatinglabel
        id="home"
        class=''
        label="Home"
        inputValue='{{webPage.home}}'
        error="{{error_msg}}"
        validate='{{regex}}'>
      </paper-input>
```

In my Dart Script

```
@observable String regex = r"(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?";
```

Apologies for the previous post where the incorrect regex was used.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new question you should fix and improve the original question.